# Babel does not transpile code when using Webpack's resolve modules

Tags: webpack, babeljs, webpack-2

or so it seems,

The code transpiles if I use regular relative paths, but when I use `resolve.modules` I get this error message:

```
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| export default class Test {
|
|     name = 'Joe';
|
|     constructor() {
      ...
```

webpack.config:

```
...
resolve: {
    modules: [
        path.resolve(__dirname,'resources/assets/app'),
        path.resolve('./node_modules')
    ],
},

module: {
...
```

app/core/Test.js:

```
export default class Test {

    name = 'Joe';

    constructor() {
        console.log('construct a Test');
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
import Test from 'core/Test';
```

Does anyone know if this is a bug or am I missing something?

I get the same error when using `resolve.alias`

Have also tried using `babel-plugin-transform-class-properties`

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "stage-0",
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties",
    "react-hot-loader/babel",
    "transform-async-to-generator",
    "transform-decorators-legacy"
  ]
}
```

Comment: You might need `extensions: [ '', '', '.js', '.jsx' ]` top level config key?

Comment: Hi. I tried that, but having the same issue. According to the docs, .js and .json are the default `extensions` values. https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-extensions

Comment: Can you share your webpack config?

Comment: Here you go, https://hastebin.com/awajuvopat.js

Comment: Ah! Found the problem. Directory in resolve.modules, `resources/assets/app` was above the babel loader's `include` value (which is `resources/assets/app/src`). Therefore the rule/loader was never triggered. Thanks!